# How to place Apps on "Home Bar" for Logitech Revue Google-TV?

Tags: google-tv, logitech-revue

How can I add apps to the home bar on the Logitech Revue Google-TV box? I can remove them by pressing and holding the OK button and selecting *remove* from the popup menu, but I haven't seen an option to add them.

The Logitech Help has stopped working - all the link report "Unable to Open URL". I am guessing this is part of Logitech's dropping of support for this device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the Menu key on the remote, and then select "Edit home screen icons" or something to that extent (wording could be different, I'm going by my Sony Google TV unit.)  Now highlight (using the arrow keys) and click on the empty box on the home bar vacated by the app you've just removed, and a pop-up should appear with all installed apps and bookmarks listed.  Selecting any of them will place it on the home bar.